# Cardinalidad en workbench en modelo

Tags: mysql

no estoy encontrado información acerca de las relaciones de las tablas. La única que entiendo es la automática, pero no quiero tirar siempre de la automática. He estado mirando por internet pero no he encontrado la respuesta. Quizá tiene otro nombre, pero soy muy novata en esto. Gracias!!

Pongo toda la barra para que sepáis a lo que me refiero. Es a partir de las cardinalidades. Me refiero porque hay dos cardinalidades de cada una. Por ejemplo 1,1 tiene la flecha así - - - y otra misma relacion 1,1 tiene la flecha así –––––––– ¿Que diferencia hay - - - a –––––? No lo entiendo

[image: barra workbench]

Comment: Cuando tienes las líneas de las relaciones dibujadas entre las dos tablas, si das doble click en ellas, puedes cambiar la relación creo recordar. ¿A eso te refieres?

Comment: He modificado la pregunta. No me refiero a eso @cnbandicoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las relaciones identificadas con `----` se refieren a relaciones NO identificadoras, mientras que las identificadas con `_____` se refieren a relaciones identificadoras.

El calificativo"'**identificadora**" indica si los atributos que forman parte de la clave foránea (lado N de la relación) deben formar parte también de la clave primaria de dicha entidad, lo que ocurre si una tabla proviene de un tipo de entidad débil o en el caso de atributos de tablas que provienen de tipos de relación N:M.

En definitiva, una relación **identificadora** es cuando una tabla depende de la otra para existir.

Comment: Yo pensaba que se trataba de clave fuerte (campo no acepta null) o débil (campo acepta null).

Comment: Quizás este enlace también sea útil de incluirlo: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-vertical-toolbar.html

Answer (score 1):

**Actualización**: Pregunta editada.

Como dice [@cnbandicoot](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/47147/6251) la que es línea continua implica obligatoriedad mientras que la otra no.

---

Tienes la cardinalidad de las relaciones entre tablas en esa barra en la parte de abajo.

Según [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_entidad-relaci%C3%B3n#Correspondencia_de_cardinalidades):

> **Uno a Uno**: (1:1) Un registro de una entidad A se relaciona con solo un registro en una entidad B. (ejemplo dos entidades, profesor y departamento, con llaves primarias, código_profesor y jefe_depto respectivamente, un profesor solo puede ser jefe de un departamento y un departamento solo puede tener un jefe).
>
> **Uno a varios**: (1:N) Un registro en una entidad en A se relaciona con cero o muchos registros en una entidad B. Pero los registros de B solamente se relacionan con un registro en A. (ejemplo: dos entidades, vendedor y ventas, con llaves primarias, código_vendedor y venta, respectivamente, un vendedor puede tener muchas ventas pero una venta solo puede tener un vendedor).
>
> **Varios a Uno**: (N:1) Una entidad en A se relaciona exclusivamente con una entidad en B. Pero una entidad en B se puede relacionar con 0 o muchas entidades en A (ejemplo empleado-centro de trabajo).
>
> **Varios a Varios**: (N:M) Una entidad en A se puede relacionar con 0 o con muchas entidades en B y viceversa (ejemplo asociaciones-ciudadanos, donde muchos ciudadanos pueden pertenecer a una misma asociación, y cada ciudadano puede pertenecer a muchas asociaciones distintas).

Para utilizarlas simplemente creas las dos tablas con sus claves, seleccionas la relación pertinente y con ella seleccionada haces click en la tabla de origen y luego en la de destino. Automáticamente te creará las referencias según la relación elegida